# Which items are sensitive to MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE?

Tags: java, android, motion-detection

I am setting `OnTouchListener` to a Button, I can check if motion type is `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE`. On the other hand if it is `TextView`, I cannot get any moment of `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE`

For example take a look at the code below:

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent me) {
    if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        Log.e(TAG,"1");
    }
    if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        Log.e(TAG,"2");
    } else if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        Log.e(TAG,"3");
    }
    return false;
}
```

if I bind this listener to a Button, I can see "3" in my logs, on the other hand, if I bind this to an `ImageView` or etc. I cannot see any "3". but "1" and "2" are acting normal for both situation.

So the question is (if I am not mistaken) which items are `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` sensitive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try implementing `OnClickListener` also..like this..and put `onClick` empty.. I think it then detects ACTION_MOVE, along with ACTION_UP and ACTION_DOWN..

```
class MyActivity implements View.OnTouchListerner, View.OnClickListener{
    .....
    public void onClick(View v) {}
    .....
}
```

Comment: err.. even i dont know.. got it from some blog... :D

Comment: you know about other fields, views, widgets (components etc.); can they be made ACTION_MOVE sensitive by this way (if they have not already) ?

Answer (score 0):

Textview doen't hava any MotionEvent ActionMove, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html..

Thanks...

Comment: So the question is (if I am not mistaken) **which items** are MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE sensitive?